# Compilation Errors Not Readable

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, terminal

I use gcc to write C programs in Ubuntu. For some reason, the output of compilation is not readable in terminal until it is copied and pasted into a text editor. Here's a sample C code with compilation error and how it is visible in my terminal.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("%d", argd);
}
```

**Compilation Result in Terminal**

[image: Compilation Result in Terminal]

**Compilation Result Copied to Text Editor**

[image: Compilation Result Copied to Text Editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could your terminal colorscheme be messed up? GCC might be running and outputting black or clear text on your terminal. Try running it with `-fdiagnostics-color=never` and see if that makes a difference ([docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Language-Independent-Options.html)).

If that is is the problem, either adjust your terminal emulator's color scheme (different for each one), or GCC's output (instructions in docs).

Comment: Yes, using `-fdiagnostics-color=never` flag in gcc prints everything correctly. Thanks :).

Comment: @Learner Great!

Answer (score 0):

You can control GCC color output through `GCC_COLORS` env variable.

In particular you should set some color different for `quote` text.

Add in your configuration (`$HOME/.bashrc` if you use bash)

```
export GCC_COLORS="quote=01:32"
```

To have it bold green. Check [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Language-Independent-Options.html) for more information.

Disclaimer: this work well only if you have not messed up too much your terminal profile ;)

Answer (score 0):

2 Questions:

Can you see the texts when you mark the empty fields?

Did you try changing the colors of your terminal? If no theres a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558280/changing-colour-of-text-and-background-of-terminal) where its explained